# Can I find out what type of mobile phone is connected via Bluetooth to a Linux PC?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Is it an Android phone or IOs? Of course on the PC side. I want to implement different behavior of my code depending on the OS on the connected phone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Bluetooth Perspective, you cannot find which OS version/OS/model is connected. This information can be modified in a phone (by changing name, service records etc.).

If you have your own application running on the phone, that is connected to the PC, then it is possible for your application to read the information(from the phone) and send it through Bluetooth Serial port (or) object exchange profile (or) by registering a record in the bluetooth service discovery database of the phone. If you can register a SDP record with the model and os information through your app, then it is possible to know the model , without establishing a active connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not have friendly applications on the phone. It can be any phone.

Comment: You can also find based on by Mac address https://macaddresschanger.com/bluetooth-mac-lookup.   But please be aware only apple devices can be trusted for others the information may point to either device manufacturer or Bluetooth chip vendoe